# How to pass a list of tuples in template file from views so I can separately iterate each data member in template?

Tags: python, django, database, backend

I'm working on a django project , I got a list of tuples accessed from postgres database using psycopg2. Now I want to pass this list of tuples to my template file in such way that I can access each element of individual tuple. As I have to put this data into a html table.

views.py file :

```
    def search_owner_prop(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        o_no = request.POST.get('owner_num')
        conn = psycopg2.connect(database="dreamhomeproperty", user="postgres", password="****", host="*****",
                                port="****")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute(f''' SELECT property_for_rent.property_n,private_owner.fname,property_for_rent.street,property_for_rent.rooms,property_for_rent.typee FROM dreamhome_schema.property_for_rent 
INNER JOIN dreamhome_schema.private_owner
ON property_for_rent.owner_number={o_no} AND private_owner.owner_no={o_no}''')
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        conn.close()
        return render(request,'owner_with_prop.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'search_owner_prop.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display in templates, simply you can pass context in views.

Now pass the context here:

```
return render(request,'owner_with_prop.html',{'rows':rows}) #rows is a context from views
```

And in templates:

```
{% for tuple in rows %}
  {{tuple}}
{% endfor %}
```

Using above code, you can display all tuples which is fetched.

Comment: Yes , I tried this. It is working but it is displaying tuples like this in template:
(tuple data ,tuple data)

Comment: But I want to access only single index data , so I can add it in my html table

Comment: {{tuple.indexname}} try this way